Проблема с слайдером на мобильной версии: слайды не центрируются, иногда дублируются и со временем сбивается автоскролл и позиционирование
У меня возникла проблема с слайдером на мобильной версии сайта, и я не могу понять, в чем именно заключается ошибка. На мобильной версии слайды не центрируются как нужно. В результате, элементы иногда уезжают в сторону, а иногда слайды дублируются. При этом через некоторое время центрирование слайдов вообще сбивается, и слайды начинают вести себя нестабильно, на десктоп версии это не особо ощутимо т.к. контейнер на всю ширину экрана,а в мобильной версии мне просто нужно что бы при ручном и авто скролле слайд был ровно по центру. Я только начал изучать JS, поэтому не могу разобраться,уже 2 дня потратил, буду рад вашей помощи!


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
  const slides = Array.from(wrapper.children);
  const leftButton = document.querySelector(".scroll-button.left");
  const rightButton = document.querySelector(".scroll-button.right");

  function getSlideWidth() {
    const slide = slides[0]; // Первый слайд
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(slide);
    const marginRight = parseInt(style.marginRight, 10) || 0; // Учитываем отступ между слайдами
    return slide.getBoundingClientRect().width + marginRight;
  }

  const slideWidth = getSlideWidth();

  // Дублируем слайды для бесконечного скролла
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    const cloneStart = slide.cloneNode(true);
    const cloneEnd = slide.cloneNode(true);
    wrapper.appendChild(cloneEnd); // Дублируем в конец
    wrapper.insertBefore(cloneStart, wrapper.firstChild); // Дублируем в начало
  });

  const originalSlidesCount = slides.length;

  wrapper.scrollLeft = originalSlidesCount * slideWidth;



  // Корректировка положения
  function correctScrollPosition() {
    const maxScrollLeft = (originalSlidesCount * 2 - 1) * slideWidth;

    if (wrapper.scrollLeft < originalSlidesCount * slideWidth - slideWidth / 2) {
      wrapper.scrollLeft += originalSlidesCount * slideWidth;
    } else if (wrapper.scrollLeft > maxScrollLeft + slideWidth / 2) {
      wrapper.scrollLeft -= originalSlidesCount * slideWidth;
    }
  }

  // Прокрутка влево
  leftButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const targetScrollLeft = wrapper.scrollLeft - slideWidth;
    wrapper.scrollTo({
      left: targetScrollLeft,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });

    setTimeout(correctScrollPosition, 300); // Исправляем после анимации
  });

  // Прокрутка вправо
  rightButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const targetScrollLeft = wrapper.scrollLeft + slideWidth;
    wrapper.scrollTo({
      left: targetScrollLeft,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });

    setTimeout(correctScrollPosition, 300); // Исправляем после анимации
  });

  // Корректируем позицию при ручной прокрутке
  wrapper.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    clearTimeout(wrapper.isScrolling);
    wrapper.isScrolling = setTimeout(correctScrollPosition, 100);
  });

  // Автоскролл
  const intervalTime = 5000; // Интервал в миллисекундах
  let autoScroll = setInterval(() => {
    const targetScrollLeft = wrapper.scrollLeft + slideWidth;
    wrapper.scrollTo({
      left: targetScrollLeft,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });

    setTimeout(correctScrollPosition, 300); // Исправляем после анимации
  }, intervalTime);

  // Остановка автоскролла при наведении мыши
  wrapper.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => clearInterval(autoScroll));

  // Возобновление автоскролла при убирании мыши
  wrapper.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    autoScroll = setInterval(() => {
      const targetScrollLeft = wrapper.scrollLeft + slideWidth;
      wrapper.scrollTo({
        left: targetScrollLeft,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });

      setTimeout(correctScrollPosition, 300);
    }, intervalTime);
  });
});
.scroll-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* Скрываем полосу прокрутки */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  /* Chrome, Safari и Opera */
}

.content-item {
  flex: 0 0 608px;
  /* Фиксированная ширина слайда */
  height: 200px;
  /* Высота слайда */
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  /* Для позиционирования заголовка */
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Адаптация фонового изображения */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* Лёгкая тень */
}

.content-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.content-text h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
}

.content-text p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666666;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.scroll-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  border: none
}

.scroll-button.left {
  left: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.scroll-button.right {
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.scroll-button span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
}

.scroll-button:hover {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.scroll-button:active {
  background-color: #e2e6ea;
}

.scroll-button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.icon-container {
  position: absolute;
  /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
  top: 50%;
  /* Центрируем по вертикали */
  right: 20px;
  /* Отступ от правого края */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Корректируем вертикальное центрирование */
}

.icon-container img {
  width: 160px;
  /* Размер иконки */
  height: 160px;
  object-fit: contain;
  /* Сохраняем пропорции */
}


}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    /* Отключаем горизонтальную прокрутку */
  }
  
  .content-item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    /* Слайд занимает 100% ширины экрана */
    height: 200px;
    /* Задайте нужную высоту */
    margin-right: 0;
    /* Убираем отступы между слайдами */
  }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .category-item img {
    scale: 1.5
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .scroll-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative
  }
  
  .content-item {
    flex: 0 0 90%;
    /* Слайды занимают 90% ширины экрана */
    height: 150px;
    /* Уменьшаем высоту для мобильных */
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    gap: 5px;
    /* Уменьшаем отступы между слайдами */
    padding: 5px;
    /* Сужаем внутренние отступы */
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .content-item {
    flex: 0 0 95%;
    /* Слайды занимают почти всю ширину экрана */
    height: 120px;
    /* Ещё меньше высота для маленьких экранов */
  }
  
  .icon-container img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
  .wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .scroll-button {
    display: none;
  }
}
<div class="scroll-container">
  <button class="scroll-button left"><span> &lt;</span></button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#EBD8F4">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Osalege konkursil</h2>
        <p>Saage võitjaks ja võitke väärtuslikke auhindu!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/cup.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#ADD2FF">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Postitage kuulutusi</h2>
        <p>Rääkige maailmale oma toodetest ja teenustest!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/pen.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#FEEE99">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Turvalisuse juhend</h2>
        <p>Kuidas vältida petuskeeme?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/security.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#F3E1D7">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Vaheta oma kaup</h2>
        <p>Vaheta vana uue vastu — lihtsalt ja mugavalt!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/exchange.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#F3E1D7">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Vaheta oma kaup</h2>
        <p>Vaheta vana uue vastu — lihtsalt ja mugavalt!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/exchange.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#FEEE99">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Turvalisuse juhend</h2>
        <p>Kuidas vältida petuskeeme?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/security.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#ADD2FF">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Postitage kuulutusi</h2>
        <p>Rääkige maailmale oma toodetest ja teenustest!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/pen.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#EBD8F4">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Osalege konkursil</h2>
        <p>Saage võitjaks ja võitke väärtuslikke auhindu!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/cup.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#F3E1D7">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Vaheta oma kaup</h2>
        <p>Vaheta vana uue vastu — lihtsalt ja mugavalt!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/exchange.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#FEEE99">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Turvalisuse juhend</h2>
        <p>Kuidas vältida petuskeeme?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/security.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#ADD2FF">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Postitage kuulutusi</h2>
        <p>Rääkige maailmale oma toodetest ja teenustest!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/pen.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color:#EBD8F4">
      <div class="content-text">
        <h2>Osalege konkursil</h2>
        <p>Saage võitjaks ja võitke väärtuslikke auhindu!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-container">
        <img src="https://h2h.ee/assets/img/icons_slider/cup.png" alt="Icon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="scroll-button right"><span> &gt;</span></button>
</div>



